# Syntax issue writing conditional mySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mySQL query written in the format of a PHP PDO script. I made sure to verify that all of the columns I refer to in the query exist.

So the issue seems to do with the syntax of the query itself. When executing the query in POSTMAN I see the issue seems to be where the if statement beings.

**The following is the query:**

```
   $stmt = $conn->prepare('IF EXISTS (SELECT * `Table1` WHERE `code`= :code )
    UPDATE `Table1`
    SET `code_stat` = 2
    WHERE code = :code
ELSE
    INSERT INTO `Table1` (`code`,`code_stat`)
    VALUES (:code, 2 ) ' );

                $stmt->execute([
                'code' => $_POST['code']
                ]);
```

Comment: You could try `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO` and simplify your query quite a bit. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

Comment: You might instead look at INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: What is the error message that PDO gives you?

Comment: @Dharman I get the following error: `SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
`Table1 WHERE `code`= ? )
UPDATE `Table1' at line 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Comment: Alot of people are referring me to the ON DUPLICATE KEY method  the problem with this is the column `code` is not the primary key it is an index key..how would this method work with index key?

Comment: @Dharman Does the query look for duplicates in either the primary key or the index key columns?

Comment: RTM: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html *"UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY"*

Comment: I appreciate your help @Dharman

Answer (score 0):

Think you're just missing the ‘FROM’.

```
SELECT * `Table1` WHERE
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM `Table1` WHERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("REPLACE INTO `Table` (`code`,`code_stat`) VALUES (:code,2)");

$stmt->execute(['code' => $_POST['code']);
```

If the row does not exists, it will be inserted otherwise it will be updated.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html